# Convert Excel VBA for PivotChart

Tags: excel, vba, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I am writing code to create an Excel PivotChart, without a visible PivotTable.  Apparently, I am unable to do this via Excel_TLB, (as per another question on Stackoverflow), so I am using ComObj and Excel2010.  My code create the PivotChart successfully.  I am now trying to set certain filters.  I have captured the relevant VBA code, but I cannot get it converted to Delphi.  The VBA code is

```
  ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields( _
        "[Range].[Revenue Type Group].[Revenue Type Group]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Range].[Revenue Type Group].&[NEW]", _
        "[Range].[Revenue Type Group].&[WORKLOAD]")
```

My Delphi Code (only setting one value) is

```
 XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields['[Range].[Revenue Type Group].[Revenue Type Group]'].VisibleItemsList[1] := '[Range].[Revenue Type Group].&[NEW]';
```

While I can compile, at runtime I get "Does not support a collection" exception.

I don't see anything odd in the MS VBA doc about this...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.visibleitemslist

I have also TRIED using a dynamic array such as

```
SetLength(A1, 1);
  A1[0] := '[Range].[Revenue Type Group].&[NEW]';
  XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields['[Range].[Revenue Type Group].[Revenue Type Group]'].VisibleItemsList := A1;
```

This will NOT compile with the error 'Type not allowed in Variant Dispatch call.
I have tried defining A1 as array of string, array of variant and array of Olevariant.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: [`PivotFields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.pivotfields) is a method, not an array property.

Comment: Oliver -  ShowMessage(XLApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields['[Range].[Revenue Type Group].[Revenue Type Group]'].Name); works and displays as expected, so I don't think PivotFields syntax is the issue.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `VarArrayCreate()` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619753/how-to-use-variant-arrays-in-delphi)).

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if the question contained [MRE].

Comment: The VBA code can't be correct with an odd sum of brackets.

Comment: @Olivier - VarArrayCreate did the trick.  Submit as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the array with [`VarArrayCreate()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Variants.VarArrayCreate). A regular Delphi array is not accepted when using a COM object.